# How can I get tox and poetry to work together to support testing multiple versions of a Python dependency?

Tags: django, tox, python-poetry

I am switching a project that currently uses `pipenv` to `poetry` as a test to see what the differences are. The project is a simple, redistributable, Django app. It supports Python 3.6-8, and Django 2.2 and 3.0. I have a `tox.ini` file that covers all combinations of Python and Django thus:

```
[tox]
envlist = py{36,37,38}-django{22,30}

[testenv]
whitelist_externals = poetry
skip_install = true

deps =
    django22: Django==2.2
    django30: Django==3.0

commands =
    poetry install -vvv
    poetry run pytest --cov=my_app tests/
    poetry run coverage report -m
```

The problem that I am having (which does not exist in the `pipenv` world) is that the `poetry install` statement will always overwrite whatever is in the `deps` section with whatever is in the `poetry.lock` file (which will be auto-generated if it does not exist). This means that the test matrix will never test against Django 2.2 - as each tox virtualenv gets Django 3.0 installed by default.

I don't understand how this is supposed to work - should installing dependencies using `poetry` respect the existing environment into which it is being installed, or not?

So - my question is - how do I set up a multi-version tox (or travis) test matrix, with poetry as the dependency manager?

My `pyproject.toml` defines Python / Django versions as:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.6"
django = "^2.2 || ^3.0"
```

The generated `poetry.lock` file (not committed) has this Django version information:

```
[[package]]
category = "main"
description = "A high-level Python Web framework that encourages rapid development and clean, pragmatic design."
name = "django"
optional = false
python-versions = ">=3.6"
version = "3.0"
```

---

UPDATE: include clean tox output

This is the result when I delete the lock file, and recreate the tox environment. As you can see, tox installs `Django==2.2` as a dependency in the virtualenv, but `poetry` then updates this to `3.0` when it installs.

I need a solution that runs the poetry install, respecting existing package installs. i.e. if `pyproject.toml` states `Django = "^2.2 || ^3.0"`, and 2.2 is already installed, then pin to that version - don't attempt to upgrade.

```
my-app$ tox -r -e py36-django22
py36-django22 recreate: .tox/py36-django22
py36-django22 installdeps: Django==2.2
py36-django22 installed: Django==2.2,my-app==0.1.0,pytz==2019.3,sqlparse==0.3.0
py36-django22 run-test: commands[0] | poetry install -vvv
Using virtualenv: .tox/py36-django22
Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies...
   1: derived: django (^2.2 || ^3.0)
   ...
PyPI: 10 packages found for django >=2.2,<4.0
   ...
   1: Version solving took 3.330 seconds.
   1: Tried 1 solutions.

Writing lock file

Package operations: 52 installs, 1 update, 0 removals, 3 skipped

  - ...
  - Updating django (2.2 -> 3.0)
  - ...
```

UPDATE 2

Following instructions from sinoroc below - I have updated the tox file to remove `skip_dist` and include `isolated_build`. This works, sort of. tox builds the package, and installs it - but only the non-dev version, which does not include `pytest`, `coverage` and a host of linting tools that I'd like to include at a later point. i.e. the tools I want to run through tox are specified as dev-dependencies in poetry. There is a solution here, to include all of these inside the tox file - but that seems self-defeating - as then I have poetry and tox both declaring dependencies.

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.6"
django = "^2.2 || ^3.0"

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
pytest = "^3.0"
pytest-cov = "^2.8"
pytest-django = "^3.7"
coverage = "^4.5"
pylint = "^2.4"
pylint-django = "^2.0"
flake8 = "^3.7"
flake8-bandit = "^2.1"
flake8-docstrings = "^1.5"
isort = "^4.3"
mypy = "^0.750.0"
pre-commit = "^1.20"
black = "=19.3b0"
```

---

UPDATE 3: solution

```
[tox]
isolated_build = True
envlist = lint, mypy, py{36,37,38}-django{22,30}

[travis]
python =
    3.6: lint, mypy, py36
    3.7: lint, mypy, py37
    3.8: lint, mypy, py38

[testenv]
deps =
    pytest
    pytest-cov
    pytest-django
    coverage
    django22: Django==2.2
    django30: Django==3.0

commands =
    django-admin --version
    pytest --cov=my_app tests/

[testenv:lint]
deps =
    pylint
    pylint-django
    flake8
    flake8-bandit
    flake8-docstrings
    isort
    black

commands =
    isort --recursive my_app
    black my_app
    pylint my_app
    flake8 my_app

[testenv:mypy]
deps =
    mypy

commands =
    mypy my_app
```

Comment: Not a _poetry_ user myself, so not 100% sure as I can't test it, but... I would try following [this advice](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example/package.html#poetry), as well as removing `skip_install` and `whitelist_externals`, and use the commands directly without `poetry install` or `poetry run` in `commands`.

Comment: I think it would be more clear to move the solution into its own answer :)

Comment: Also, such solution should mention it accepts the tradeoff to repeat dev requirements and does not benefit from any poetry locking

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Haven't thoroughly tested it, but I believe something like this should work:

```
[tox]
envlist = py{36,37,38}-django{22,30}
isolated_build = True

[testenv]
deps =
    django22: Django==2.2
    django30: Django==3.0
    # plus the dev dependencies
    pytest
    coverage

commands =
    pytest --cov=my_app tests/
    coverage report -m
```

See the ["*poetry*" section in the "packaging" chapter of the *tox* documentation](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/3.14.3/example/package.html#poetry).

---

In order to avoid the repetition of the *dev* dependencies, one could try the following variation based on the [*extras* feature](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#extras):

`tox.ini`

```
[tox]
# ...

[testenv]
# ...
deps =
    django22: Django==2.2
    django30: Django==3.0
extras =
    test
```

`pyproject.toml`

```
[tool.poetry]
# ...

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.6"
django = "^2.2 || ^3.0"
#
pytest = { version = "^5.2", optional = true }

[tool.poetry.extras]
test = ["pytest"]

[build-system]
# ...
```

---

Nowadays there are *tox* plug-ins that try to make for a better integration with *poetry*-based projects:

- [*`tox-poetry-installer`*](https://pypi.org/project/tox-poetry-installer/)
- [*`tox-poetry-dev-dependencies`*](https://pypi.org/project/tox-poetry-dev-dependencies/) (disclaimer: my project)
- [*`tox-poetry`*](https://pypi.org/project/tox-poetry/)

Comment: This is very close - so thank you for that (`isolated_build` is the key) - however it's installing the non-dev dependencies only, which means that it cannot find `pytest` to actually run the tests. Ideally, all the dependencies for running tests (`pytest`, `coverage`, etc.) would be in dev-dependencies and not packaged with the app.

Comment: I think it used the dev dependencies in my quick test, but I don't remember clearly, I didn't spend much time on it. But yes, I get the point that the dev dependencies are now both in poetry and tox. With setuptools I set the dev dependencies as extras and tell tox to install the extras.

Comment: @Hugo I updated the answer to show a suggestion of how to avoid repeating the _dev_ dependencies. It works perfectly for my use cases, but I can see how it has its drawbacks for other use cases though...