# Tox running test against already activated virtualenv instead of creating isolated virtualenv with envlist and running test in it

Tags: python, python-poetry, tox

I'm struggling with *tox* tool. I have *tox* installed in my activated virtual environment, lets call the virtual environment `parentenv`. I basically use *tox* to test my project against different versions of Python. Based on my understanding of *tox*, it's supposed create isolated virtual environments, install all dependencies and run test in those isolated virtual environments. The error I'm facing is that *tox* is able to created these virtual environments but fails to activate these isolated virtual environments and rather uses the virtual environment of the project (i.e.: `parentenv`) and run the tests in that environment.

Below is the content of my `tox.ini` located in the project's root directory. All commands are run from the root directory.

`tox.ini`

```ini
[tox]
envlist = py39, py310
skipsdist = true

[testenv]
allowlist_externals = poetry
commands =
    poetry install -v
    poetry run pytest here
```

My Workflow is (commands are run from the project's root directory):

```
$ poetry shell
$ tox
```

Below is a sample output from running `tox`:

[sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPORb.png)

Comment: Isn't the issue that Poetry always handles the virtual environment on its own (in other words, it ignores that a virtual environment is already active, the *tox* one)? -- Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59377071

Answer (score 1):

Having a look at your "sample output", the second marked line is not from tox, but from poetry.

You should have a look at the official documentation of poetry for tox:
https://python-poetry.org/docs/faq/#is-tox-supported

The differences at first sight:

- you need to configure the build backend (unclear whether you did it as you did not show us your pyproject.toml)
- you need to use the `isolated_build` directive in your tox.ini

Comment: I have configured the backend build. This is a snippet from my pyproject.toml 
 [build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api". I have also tried the tox.ini settings from the link you share but yet still the error persist

Comment: `isolated_build` is the default on tox v4+, isn't it?